# When using isDisplayed, result is "Expected false to be true", even when web elements are displayed on the screen

Tags: protractor

In my spec file, I am identifying a web element and then performing action like unpublish and then identifying the new status by verifying the button label as "Publish".

My Article_Spec file is as below,

```
    //Article_spec//

'use strict';

var FunLib = require('/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Function_Lib.js'); 
var ArticlePO = require('/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Article_PO.js'); 

describe('News: ', function() {

var FuncLib;
var Article;

FuncLib = new FunLib();
Article = new ArticlePO();

//scenario 1: Navigate to News Menu
it('Navigate to News menu', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    FuncLib.SelectMenu.get(0).click(); //Click on News Menu
    console.log('Article menu is clicked.');
    browser.sleep(3500);
    expect(FuncLib.SelectSubMenu.getText()).toEqual(["News", "Partners", "My News", "New article"]); // Verify the Submenus: News, Partners, My News, New article are present
});
//scenario 15: Verify published news can be unpublished
it('Verify published news can be unpublished', function() {
    FuncLib.SelectSubMenu.get(2).click(); // Click on "New article" submenu 
    console.log('My News submenu is clicked.');
    browser.sleep(7000);
    Article.MyArticle.isDisplayed().then(function(result1) {
    console.log(result1);
        if (result1){
            Article.MyArticle.click();
            Article.Unpublish.isDisplayed().then(function(result2) {
                if (result2) {
                    console.log('Published article is available');
                    Article.Unpublish.click();
                    Article.Publish.isDisplayed().then(function(result3) {
                        if (result3) {
                        console.log('Article unpublished successfully');
                        }
                        else {
                        console.log('Article is not unpublished.');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                console.log('Can not unpublish as all articles are unpublished.');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
        console.log('No articles are available on My News screen');
        }
    });
});
```

My Article PO file is as below,

```
//Article Page object file - Article_PO.js
'use strict';

var ArticlePO = function(){

this.Title = element(by.model('article.title'));
this.Header = element(by.model('article.header'));
this.ImgFooter = element(by.model('article.cover_footer'));
this.ArtDsc = element.all(by.css('.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ta-bind')).get(0);
this.KeyWrd = element(by.model('$mdChipsCtrl.chipBuffer'));
this.msg1 = "Title is missing";
this.msg2 = "Insert title, image, header and body before publishing your New.";
this.msg3 = "ARTICLE SAVED";
this.msg4 = "ERROR_UPLOADING_FILE";
this.MyArticle = element.all(by.css('.md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column')).get(0);
//element.all(by.css('[ng-class="{ notint: !item.is_published }"]'));

this.PreviewTab = element.all(by.css('.md-fab.md-accent.md-mini.md-button.md-white-theme.md-ink-ripple')).first();
this.EditTab = element.all(by.css('.md-fab.md-accent.md-mini.center.md-button.md-white-theme.md-ink-ripple'));
this.Unpublish = element.all(by.buttonText("UNPUBLISH"));
this.Publish = element.all(by.buttonText("PUBLISH"));
this.deleteArt = element(by.css('[ng-click="deleteArticle($event, item)"]'));
this.LastArticle = element.all(by.css('[ng-class="{ notint: !item.is_published }"]')).last();
this.ConfirmDelete = element(by.css('.md-dialog-content'));
};
module.exports = ArticlePO;
```

Problem I am facing here is, even when my screen has multiple articles

```
Article.MyArticle.isDisplayed().then(function(result1) {
```

return as false. And so the output of this script is 'No articles are available on My News screen'.

Console output is as below,

```
Rohits-MacBook-Pro:FFAutomation rohitgathibandhe$ /Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor conf.js
Report destination:   target/screenshots/Report.html
Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
Browser title is: ForFirm
.When registred email Id and password is entered user logged in successfully
Logged in user is : Guglielmo Della Valle
.Article menu is clicked.
.My News submenu is clicked.
false
No articles are available on My News screen

4 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 131.21 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] firefox #01 passed
Closing report
```

Other details are as below: protractor@3.2.2, nodeVersion: 4.2.4, npmVersion: 2.14.12, jasmine: 2.4.1, selenium-webdriver: 2.52.0, firefox: 46.0.1

Please tell me what is going wrong here. I want to get correct result.

HTML code is added below for the object: first article

```
<div ng-class="{ notint: !item.is_published }" ng-if="item.manageable" class="manage overlay ng-scope layout-column flex"><div class="md-whiteframe-z2 controls layout-column"><div class="button-row layout-row"><div class="border-right flex"><a class="md-fab md-accent md-mini md-button md-white-theme md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" href="/article/view/378-test" md-theme="white"><ng-md-icon icon="visibility" size="20" class="ng-scope"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" height="20"><path d="M12 17c-2.76 0-5-2.24-5-5s2.24-5 5-5 5 2.24 5 5-2.24 5-5 5zm0-12.5C7 4.5 2.73 7.61 1 12c1.73 4.39 6 7.5 11 7.5s9.27-3.11 11-7.5c-1.73-4.39-6-7.5-11-7.5z"></path><path d="M12 9c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3s1.34 3 3 3 3-1.34 3-3-1.34-3-3-3z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon></a></div><div class="border-right flex"><a class="md-fab md-accent md-mini center md-button md-white-theme md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" href="/article/edit/378" md-theme="white"><ng-md-icon icon="edit" size="20" class="ng-scope"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" height="20"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25z"></path><path d="M20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon></a></div><div class="flex"><button class="md-fab md-accent md-mini right md-button md-white-theme md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="deleteArticle($event, item)" md-theme="white"><ng-md-icon icon="delete" size="20" class="ng-scope"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" height="20"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12z"></path><path d="M19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon></button></div></div><button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-2 md-button md-noga-theme md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="togglePublish(item)" md-theme="noga" ng-show="item.is_published" aria-hidden="false"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">UNPUBLISH</span></button><button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-1 md-button md-ink-ripple ng-hide" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="togglePublish(item)" ng-show="!item.is_published" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">PUBLISH</span></button></div></div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the first element in MyArticle?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to identify first article and then perform action on it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, thanks for providing the entire test, the console output, the page objects, and the html. Very helpful!

One problem is that the console logging message are not displaying within the context of the control flow. That is, the messages may be appearing BEFORE the test even starts running, because the protractor actions are deferred as asynchronous calls while the console.log happens immediately. To fix that, put console.log message inside the deferred statements like this:

```
//scenario 1: Navigate to News Menu
it('Navigate to News menu', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //Click on News Menu
    FuncLib.SelectMenu.get(0).click().then(function() {
        // put console.log HERE so that it executes at the right time
        console.log('Article menu is clicked.'); 
    }); 
    browser.sleep(3500).then(function() {
        console.log('slept for 3500ms');
    });
    expect(FuncLib.SelectSubMenu.getText()).toEqual(["News", "Partners", "My News", "New article"]); // Verify the Submenus: News, Partners, My News, New article are present
});

//scenario 15: Verify published news can be unpublished
it('Verify published news can be unpublished', function() {
    // Click on "New article" submenu 
    FuncLib.SelectSubMenu.get(2).click().then(function() {
        console.log('My News submenu is clicked.');
    });
    browser.sleep(7000).then(function() {
        console.log('slept for 7000ms');
    });
    Article.MyArticle.isDisplayed().then(function(articleIsDisplayed) {
        console.log('articleIsDisplayed: ' + articleIsDisplayed);
        if (articleIsDisplayed){
            Article.MyArticle.click();
            Article.Unpublish.isDisplayed().then(function(unpublishIsDisplayed) {
                if (unpublishIsDisplayed) {
                    console.log('Published article is available');
                    Article.Unpublish.click();
                    Article.Publish.isDisplayed().then(function(publishIsDisplayed) {
                        if (publishIsDisplayed) {
                            console.log('Article unpublished successfully');
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Article is not unpublished.');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                console.log('Can not unpublish as all articles are unpublished.');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('No articles are available on My News screen');
        }
    });
});
```

Another problem is `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` in the first test, but not in the second test. If the page is angular, you shouldn't need to ignore synchronization (and you won't need all the `browser.sleep` commands). If you do need it, however, it should be in both tests, or in the `beforeEach`.

Since the `isDisplayed` promise looks right, it could be a problem with the timing (maybe takes more than 7 seconds to appear after the click?), or that the selector is wrong, or that the pageObject implementation isn't quite doing the right thing.

In your test, try replacing `Article.MyArticle.isDisplayed()` with `element(by.css('.md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column')).isDisplayed()` to try finding the element without using the pageObject. If that works, then try changing it to `element.all(...).get(0).isDisplayed()` in the test. If it is able to find the element that way, then we could work on updating the pageObjects.

Comment: As suggested by you I have added beforeEach for browser.ignoreSynchronization = true, also used element(by.css('.md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column')).isDisplayed(), instead of Page object but I am still getting the same result. console log is: WARNING - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column) - the first result will be used
articleIsDisplayed: false
If you see warning, many objects with same locator is available on the screen, right? then why articleIsDisplayed: false?

Comment: You're right, the warning is good, indicating that it found some elements with that selector. And it will use the first one by default, which is fine, since you want to check if the first one is displayed. Since isDisplayed is returning false, it could be that the element is present but not visible to a user. Try `element.all(...).isDisplayed().then(function(resultsArray) { resultsArray.forEach(function(result) { console.log(result); }); });`, this will tell how many elements it found, and how many of them are displayed by printing a list of boolean values to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){
    #your code here
    return this;
}
```

Maybe element is not loaded and u have to wait for it to appear.

Comment: Tried your code but getting same result as mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score -1):

I Stand corrected! using  `first()` and `get(0)` in your case is same. The issue here i think is calling the element in page object before the tests are executed as in -

```
  this.MyArticle = element.all(by.css('.md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column')).get(0);
```

The above code tries to access the element in the page object only and when try to use this in tests it is not working.

In Page Objects one should only define the Elements:

```
 this.MyArticle = element.all(by.css('.md-whiteframe-z2.controls.layout-column'));
```

And then perform some actions to that element in the tests :

```
Article.MyArticle.get(0).isDisplayed().then(function(result1) {
console.log(result1);
    if (result1){
        Article.MyArticle.click();
```

This should certainly work and Upvoting **Martin's** answer as he has also specified this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but output is false. Even I tried changing locator but output is false in all the cases.

Comment: can you post your HTML code? might be some issue locating the element because it should work!

Comment: I have added HTML code at the end of above query. Please check.

Comment: `first()` is exactly the same thing as `get(0)` Source: `ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first = function() { return this.get(0); };`

Comment: Yup, both are same just saw the code by forking protractor repo. Their api code links are broken. Thanks for correcting me I have updated my answer!